# JFrame setIconImage() works on windows but not on Mac

Tags: java, macos, jframe, icons

I was wondering if anyone knows why the following code to set the IconImage from my JFrame only works on windows but not on MacOS.

```java
public ClientGUI(String title) {
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/icons/ww_icon.png")));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried testing to see if Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(...) is returning the proper icon on Mac?

Comment: What is happening on mac?

Comment: @Jens it simply shows the default java icon

Comment: @ControlAltDel yes, its returning the proper image

Comment: Use ImageIO to load the image instead of ImageIcon - if the image fails to load for some reason, it will throw an exception

Comment: Try this: `java.net.URL url = getClass().getResource("/resources/icons/ww_icon.png"); Image image = ImageIO.read(url); setIconImage(image);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`Taskbar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Taskbar.html) class instead

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Taskbar;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    Image image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/16x16.png"));

                    Taskbar taskbar = Taskbar.getTaskbar();
                    taskbar.setIconImage(image);

                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.setIconImage(image);
                    frame.add(new TestPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {
        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(64, 64, 64, 64));
            add(new JLabel("Hello World"));
        }

    }
}
```

I'd also consider having a look at the [`Desktop`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Desktop.html) class as well